# NGINX http to https with exceptions

Tags: nginx, configuration, odoo

We have 2 files in our nginx/sites-available/ folder. The odoo-80 and the odoo-443. How can we add a exception for 1 specific path without creating a loop? If we add the exception to the 443 file it redirects back to the 80 file and opposite... Im normally working with apache and not nginx so I would be very happy for some help!

To summ up: we want this path:  /pos/web to run with http and all the rest with https.

odoo-80 file

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name odoo.server.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

location / {
rewrite ^/(.*) https://odoo.server.com:443/$1 permanent;
}}
```

Odoo-443 file

```
    #odoo server
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}


server {
 listen 443;
 server_name odoo.server.com;
 proxy_read_timeout 720s;
 proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
 proxy_send_timeout 720s;

 # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 # SSL parameters
***
 # log
***

 # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
 location /longpolling {
 proxy_pass http://odoochat;
 }

 # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://odoo;
 }

 # common gzip
 gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
 gzip on;

}

#pos20.07
#server {
#    listen 443 default_server ssl;
#    server_name odoo.server.com;
    # Force pos in http for the posbox
#    location ~ ^/pos/web {
#        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host:80$1 permanent;
#}
```

Comment: You need to add a `location` to both of the existing `server` blocks. If you use HSTS on this domain, then browsers will not be able to access this URI over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a location {} in your odoo-80 file, this should override the catch-all you have in place so it shouldn't send it to 443 in the first place.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name odoo.server.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

location ~ ^/pos/web {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odoo;
}

location / {
rewrite ^/(.*) https://odoo.server.com:443/$1 permanent;
}

}
```

Also, what Richard Smith mentioned, add the same block to 443 just in case someone types in https:// and heed his call re: HSTS (which I doubt is setup)

"we" should also be posting on Serverfault by the way :D

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I have added the 3 lines you sent me to the odoo-80 file but now it always says to many redirects... havent added anything to the 443 file

Comment: Sorry about that, I assumed you would remove the redirect and add the proxy_pass logic. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Remember to uncomment the redirect to port 80 on your 443 file so if someone uses https://something/pos/web, it redirects to http, which will then catch and use proxy_pass for the correct backend server